# Regex to remove accents, special characters but preserve dash, underline and extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove accents and special characters except dash(`-`), underline(`_`) and preserve the extension.

For example:

`ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúâêîôûàèìòùÇãç.,~!@#$%&_-12345.png`

to:

`AEIOUaeiouaeiouaeiouCac_-12345.png`

I came to this result, but the problem is that it's ignoring all dots. I need to ignore only the last occurrence to preserve the extension from filename.

```
"ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúâêîôûàèìòùÇãç.,\~!@#$%&_-12345.png".normalize('NFD').replace(/\[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\]/g, "")
```

I already tried negative look behind like this:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?<!\.)/g
```

using this [reference](https://regexr.com/54d2f), but I didn't have success.

```
"ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúâêîôûàèìòùÇãç.,~!@#$%&-12.34.5.png".normalize('NFD').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?<!\.)/g, '')
```

If I have more than a dot in this case it only removes the first `.`.

Comment: What's wrong with `.normalize('NFD').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-._]/g, '')`? It looks like it does what you want without overcomplicating

Comment: Here an idea by use of a lookahead: [`[^\w.-]+|\.(?=[^.]*\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/jFD8pJ/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negative lookahead that excludes any `.` followed by any letter or number which in turn is followed by a non-word character can work.

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9-._]|\.(?![a-zA-Z0-9]+\b)/g
```

An alternative to `[^a-zA-Z0-9-._]` is `[^\w.-]`.

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/qboAmh/4)

**Explanation**

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ``` [^a-zA-Z0-9-._] ``` | Exclude any letter, number, hyphen, underscore, and dot |
| ``` | ``` | OR |
| ``` \.(?![a-zA-Z0-9]+\b) ``` | Exclude any dot that is **NOT** followed by one or more letters and/or numbers followed by a non-word character |

**Example**

```js
const rgx = /[^a-zA-Z0-9-._]+|\.(?![a-zA-Z0-9]+\b)/g;

const str = `ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúâêîôûàèìòùÇãç.,~!@#\$%&_-12345.png`;

const file = str.replace(rgx, "");

console.log(file);
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking every charecter for being a file extension, select the whole extension at once

```
let nfd = "ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúâêîôûàèìòùÇãç.,~!@#$%&-12.34.5.png".normalize('NFD')

let exttest = nfd.replace(/(?<extension>\.[^.]+$|)(?<badchar>.?)/g, '$1')
console.log({ exttest }) // { "exttest": ".png" }

let result = nfd.replace(/(?<extension>\.[^.]+$|)(?<badchar>[^a-zA-Z0-9-]?)/g, '$1')
console.log({ result }) // { "result": "AEIOUaeiouaeiouaeiouCac-12345.png" }
```

(`(?<name>blah)` is just a named `(blah)` group, it's named just for explaining)

Answer (score 3):

In your pattern you forgot to exclude the `_` as you want to keep that in the result.

You are using a negative lookbehind that asserts that from the current position, there is not a dot directly to the left.

The negated character class `[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+` *can* match a dot, but the lookbehind `(?<!\.)` fails if it did match a dot, so it will never match any dot.

What you could do, is to match this character class `[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+`, but assert that from the current position to the right there is a dot, followed by 1+ chars except a dot or a whitespace char till the end of the string using a positive lookahead `(?=.*\.[^\s.]+$)`

```js
const result = "ÁÉÍÓÚáéí...óúâêîôûàèìòùÇãç.,~!@#$%&_-12345.png"
  .normalize('NFD')
  .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?=.*\.[^\s.]+$)/g, '');
console.log(result);
```